# Check if an inequality holds among the solutions returned by Solve

Tags: equation-solving

Let's say I solve a system:

```
Solve[{a == 3* c, b == 2 *a}, {a, b}]
```

and then want to see if the values found for `a` and `b` satisfy an inequality:

```
Reduce[a < 7 b]
```

What I would usually do is copy and paste by hand the result of the `Solve[]` to make it available to `Reduce`:

```
Solve[{a == 3* c, b == 2 *a}, {a, b}]
(output) {{a -> 3 c, b -> 6 c}}

a = 3 c;
b = 6 c;
Reduce[a < 7 b]
```

but there must be a better way to do this? I would also like all those variables (`a`,`b` and `c`) to stay local because I will have to solve a lot of similar equations with the same variable names on the same notebook and I wouldn't want the values to mix.

Comment: `{a, b} = {a, b} /. First@Solve[...]` ?

Comment: Try `First@Solve[{a == 3*c, b == 2*a}, {a, b}];
Reduce[(a < 7 b) /. %]`

Comment: @Öskå this would work but a and b are not local in this case.

Answer (score 5):

There is a reason why `Solve` returns a list of rules ;-)

```
sol = Solve[{a == 3*c, b == 2*a}, {a, b}]
Reduce[a < 7 b /. First[sol]]
```

To be a bit more verbose in my answer: a thing like `a->b` is called a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html) and it can be used to replace `a` with `b` in expressions. Hopefully, now it makes more sense to you why most solving or minimization routines return rules.

Comment: but if I try that I get as output `{c \[Element] Reals && 3 c < 42 c}` which is not the same as the "normal" output `c > 0`

Comment: @su1 I think you want `Reduce[a < 7 b /. sol]`

Comment: @su1 I was to fast, but updated my answer. Of course you *first* want to replace the solution and *then* you want to reduce it.

Comment: @su1 Additionally, note that in this case it doesn't matter whether you leave out the `First` as MrWizard did in his comment. In general solve returns a *list* of solutions, thats why you get a double nested list.

Comment: ok that would be the best solution except that sol is not a local variable. I tried `Module[{sol},
 sol = Solve[{a == 3*c, b == 2*a}, {a, b}]
   Reduce[a < 7 b /. sol]
 ]` but this gives messages like "sol$69027 is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid 
dispatch table"

Comment: @su1 you are missing a `;` in that line.  Try: `Module[{sol}, sol = Solve[{a == 3*c, b == 2*a}, {a, b}]; Reduce[a < 7 b /. sol]]` or simply: `Reduce[a < 7 b /. Solve[{a == 3*c, b == 2*a}, {a, b}]]`

Comment: @halirutan I think this question is a duplicate (see links above).  Please let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree completely. I would have been surprised if this wasn't asked before. I would prefer to close it as dup of the *newbie pitfalls* post because users which are redirected to this will definitely learn something else too. What do you think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK thanks almost there... why if I add a condition in the `Reduce`, for example `Module[{sol},
 sol = Solve[{a == 3*c, b == 2*a}, {a, b}];
 Reduce[{a < 7 b, c == 2} /. sol]
 ]` I get the error message "Reduce::naqs: "{3\ c<42\ c,c==2} is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities""? How to reduce multiple equations but keeping the replacement rule?

Comment: @su1 The issue here is that `Reduce[{{. . .}}]` is not valid input, while `Reduce[{. . .}]` is, and `{a < 7 b, c == 2} /. sol` produces `{{3 c < 42 c, c == 2}}`.  If you only want the first solution you could use `Reduce[{a < 7 b, c == 2} /. First[sol]]` or if you want all (in the case of multiple solutions) you could use `Map[Reduce, {a < 7 b, c == 2} /. sol]`.

Comment: @halirutan We got the best possible result, it being flagged as a duplicate of both due to close votes for each.  Incidentally that's something a moderator cannot do by himself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, I just saw it now and was surprised this is possible now.

Comment: Yes, it's still possible during closure, but not afterward.  I believe that each question that is marked as a duplicate during close voting will appear in the "already has an answer" header.